# Updating Images Array

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql-update, image-uploading

I have a table named `tabel_foto` which has 2 fields inside it, they are

1. `foto` (which contains the image's name), and
2. `kondisi` (which contains the image's description)

   `foto` and `kondisi`'s field value is from an-imploded multiple image upload. In other words, i have an upload form which it can upload multiple images, and those images are imploded before they are INSERTED into the sql table, like this :
   [image]

I can show the image from my table as a list like this :
[image: Preview of Uploaded File]

*Please ignore it's bad layout, it's just a prototype/experiment before i add a new feature to my site*

My question is, how to update those images to my table? I only want to update the image that is changed, i.e :

`foto`'s field value is `borobudur.jpg, bromo.jpg, merapi.jpg, prambanan.jpg`, if i update the second image (bromo.jpg) from the form, i only want to update the "bromo.jpg" string in the `foto` field, **how do i detect which image is changed on the form in php** since the file upload button is a single file upload (not multiple upload) :

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($xplode_foto); $i++) {
    ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $xplode_foto[$i]; ?>" id="<?php echo $i; ?>">
        <input type="file" id="<?php echo $i; ?>" name="foto_kondisi" onChange="previewFotoJalan(this, this.id)">
    <?php
 }
```

Thanks in advance, i appreciate any solutions and answers :)

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest you to use a different mysql schema, like this.

- photo_id
- group_id
- kondisi

Also, you can send a ajax request after every picture's upload , and refresh the page (or just a div).

This will make your life easier.. believe me... been there.

Success!!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, i've changed my question since i've done the jquery stuffs, do you mind if you read my question again?

Answer (score 0):

Considering you save images on table column as img1,img2,img3 and description as desc1,desc2,desc3
and considering you use explode to update image.

you can make change like that:

```
<?php
$id = $_POST['imgid'];
//get images string from db and save to $x;
$images_array = explode(',', $x);
unset($images_array[$id]);
$y = implode (',', $images_array);
// now save again $y to db as images


//get description string from db and save to $x;
$desc_array = explode(',', $x);
unset($desc_array [$id]);
$y = implode (',', $desc_array);
// now save again $y to db as desc
```

Hope this help you

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but please remember that not all images will be updated, it can be only 1 or 2 image(s). And if i want each input file name is unique, of course i can't write it like `<input name="foto_kondisi">`, how do i make it unique? The unique number can be obtained from the image's id

Comment: when you using explode on the images string use this generated array id to to identificate input file example
$x = explode(',' , $imagestring);
foreach($x as $key => $val) echo '<input name="image[$key]" type="file" />';

and lather on the upload php page you can get the right id and using script like in the answer update one or many you wont ;)